# Contact Form 7 WordPress Popup Display

Tags: php, wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

I'm creating a custom form using Contact Form 7 plugin for a wordpress page: 
I want to show that form in Pop up when click on a "Button".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you need OptinMonster’s pro plan which comes with the Canvas form
>   type. [OptinMonster](http://optinmonster.com/) is the best popup plugin for WordPress. you can use alternate free plugin also.

and in options Under the ‘Custom HTML’ box you will enter your contact form shortcode along with any other custom HTML you may want to add.
Here is a sample HTML we used to create the modal popup for this tutorial.

```
<h3>Do You Have Any Questions?</h3>
2
<p class="tagline">Want to ask us more about our services? Simply fill out this form and we will get back to you as soon as possible. </p>
3
[wpforms id="119"]
```

Switch back to your WordPress admin area and click on OptinMonster. You will see your list of optins. If you don’t see your optin, then click on refresh optins button.
Click on the ‘Edit output settings’ link below your optin. This will bring you to output settings for the popup.

First you need to check the box next to ‘Enable optin on site’ and ‘Load optin globally’ options. If you don’t check these, then the popup will not appear on your site.
Scroll down on the page, and you will see the option ‘Parse content for shortcodes’. Make sure it is checked, otherwise OptinMonster will not parse the shortcodes inside your popup.
Next you need to enter the shortcode that you have included in your popup. This is your contact form shortcode.
Click on the save settings to store your changes.

Create a new page in WordPress or edit a post or page where you want to add the contact form popup link or button. In the post editor switch to text editor and add your popup link like this:
1

```
<a href="#" class="manual-optin-trigger" data-optin-slug="mw7pzo63ch6wpfzi">contact us</a>
```

Don’t forget to replace the data-optin-slug with your own optin slug.
Save your changes and visit your post/page. Click on the link to see your contact form popup in action.

[check link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-contact-form-popup-in-wordpress/)

**If you want to grow your email list but don’t yet want to pay for OptinMonster, then PopupAlly is the no-fluff free WordPress popup plugin for you. With built-in advanced features this lightbox popup plugin allows you to build your list as people are about to exit your website.
Just like as OptinMonster, it also provides the Exit-intent technology. Exit-intent popups allow you to capture lost visitors and have been shown to increase conversion by over 300%.
With PopupAlly you never need to know about coding skills and still you can create advanced popup signup forms in under 5 minutes.
PopupAlly’s visual editor allows you to customize the look-and-feel of your popups with an instant preview which saves you lots of time.**
[WordPress Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popupally/)

Comment: Thanks , I'll try this.

Comment: I have to add a button in the Menu bar (right side) and on click on that button a from should open in pop up.

Comment: check updated answer